# Show/Hide table when checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

Is there a way to show/hide a table when checkbox is checked? I've done it with JavaScript, but would like to know if it can be done from code behind.

```
Protected Sub chkAccept1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkAccept1.CheckedChanged

        If chkAccept1.Checked = True Then
            tableID.Visible = True
        Else
            tableID.Visible = False

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code work. Please make sure that you have `AutoPostBack="True"`

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAccept1" AutoPostBack="True" />
<asp:Table ID="tableID" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server">
            test
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: You don't need to use an <asp:Table> for this. Just use a plain <table runat="server" id="tableId">. No point in refactoring an entire page if he doesn't need to.

Comment: @MikeHofer You are right. I just want to show the example. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Win Thank you. It worked. I was missing the AutoPostBack. Good think I didn't have to change my tables to ASP, MikeHofer your advise saved me from rewriting the entire page.

Comment: @Win Since I applied runat="server" to the tables how can I access my QueryString that is placed inside the tables. I'm getting an error `Name 'strAppID' is not declared.` Any idea?

Comment: @g_shockTan Could you please create a new ticket and post the code?